# How to prove the following hypothesis?

Tags: geometry

How can I prove that the hypothesis is true or false.

There are two points in any geometry, like a polygon. Assume that the distance between the two points is farthest and labeled as *R*. Let the centroid of the two points be the center of a circle and *R* be its radius. Can the circle cover the original geometry？

Can anybody give me some suggestion about how to prove it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So geometry = a set $S$ of points in the plane.

You get two points $P$, $Q$ of the set with the property, that their distance to each other is maximal (regarding all other pairs of points of the set):

$$
\forall A, B \in S: d(A, B) \le d(P,Q) = R
$$

You have to prove or disprove:
$$
\forall A \in S: d((P+Q)/2, A) \le R
$$
Hint: Sounds like a case for the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Definition).
\begin{align}
d((P+Q)/2, A) 
&= \lVert (P+Q)/2 - A \rVert \\
&= (1/2) \lVert P+Q - 2A \rVert \\
&= (1/2) \lVert (P-A) + (Q-A) \rVert \\
&\le (1/2) (\lVert P-A  \rVert + \lVert Q-A \rVert) \\
&\le \dotsb
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. But I think there exists some problem. You know, P+Q/2 is the center point of P and Q. Assume the center point is denoted as C, then the distance between C and A must be less than R. Because we have supposed that R is largest. Then the line starts with A, goes through C and finally intersects the geometry with K (not necessary B). But we cannot prove d(A, K)<R

Comment: $A$ stands for any any point which is part of the geometry. What kind of point was your $K$?

Comment: Yes, I understood what's your key point. I just got it wrong before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis, no point is farther then $R$ to either endpoints, so that the geometry is inscribed in a spindle shape.

[image]

Radius $\dfrac{\sqrt3}4R$ is enough to cover.

Comment: Sorry to reply late. Why the radius you mentioned is enough to cover. Can you give some proof. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Lily: establish the dimensions of the spindle.